# WPF: add several objects into my ListView - only the first one is added

Tags: wpf, listview

I have my Object that i want to add into my `ListView`:

```
Public class MyData
{
    string name {get; set;}
}
```

This is how i try to add my object behind code:

```
ObservableCollection<MyData> collection = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
            MyData data1 = new MyData("c:\file.doc");
            collection.Add(data1);
            myListView.Items.Add(collection);
```

This works fine but if i want to add another one:

```
ObservableCollection<MyData> collection = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
            MyData data1 = new MyData("c:\file.doc");
            collection.Add(data1);

            MyData data2 = new MyData("c:\blabla.doc");
            collection.Add(data2);

            myListView.Items.Add(collection);
```

I can see only the first object.

`ListView` XAML:

```
    <ListView Name="myListView" Margin="16,453,263,40" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
                <Grid Margin="-6">
                    <ProgressBar Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}" 
                                 Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=ProgressCell}" Height="16" Margin="0"
                                 Foreground="#FF5591E8" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding Progress, StringFormat={}{0}%}" FontSize="12"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ProgressBarTemplate">
                <Label  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderStyle}">
                <GridViewColumn Width="425" Header="File name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" />
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="ProgressCell"  Width="50" Header="Progress"
                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Can you post your XAML.

Comment: I would recommend using binding to do this. I would highly recommend learning the MVVM pattern, it has served me well to create usable, maintainable, technical debt free apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the collection as follows :

```
public ObservableCollection<Data> dataList { get; set; }
```

initialize it in your constructor and add the elements according to your needs. 
Set the data context of your window :

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Then data bind it in xaml :

```
<ListView Name="myListView"                 
          ItemsSource="{Binding dataList}"/>
```

It should work and you should see both elements added.

For your specific case, don't add the collection to the Items, but set the ItemsSource of your ListView.

```
myListView.ItemsSource = collection;
```

Comment: What is the differences between  Items.Add.. and ItemSource ? what happen if i will choose many items to add ? i will see the items added ongoing or only at the end i will see suddenly all the files ?

Comment: Items.Add adds one item at a time. So if you want to use it, try iterating over your collection with foreach and use myListView.Items.Add() on every item.